# How do I filter out an iterator's values where calling a function returns a Result::Err?

Tags: filter, rust, pattern-matching

How would you iterate through a list and filter out all values where the response `Result` is not `Ok`?  I want to do something like `filter_map`, but it is saying I need to return an `Option`.

```
use std::result::Result;

fn match_value(vals: i32) -> Result<i32, i32> {
    match vals {
        2 => Ok(1),
        _ => Err(0),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let values = vec![1, 2, 3, 2];
    let matching = values
        .iter()
        .map(|name| match_value(*name))
        .filter(|x| x.is_ok())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", matching);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the value contained in the `Ok`, use [`Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map), which combines iterable values into one iterator. `Option` and `Result` both implement `IntoIterator`:

```
let matching = values
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|name| match_value(*name))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

If you want the original value, just use `filter`:

```
let matching = values
    .iter()
    .filter(|&&name| match_value(name).is_ok())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

There's no need to import `Result`; it's already part of the prelude.

Comment: this is close, but i wanted the original value.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Rob I don't follow. What is the expected value of `matching`? If you had included such in your question, my wasting of your time could have been avoided.

Comment: thank you for your help, you definitely did not waste my time

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but maybe you wanted sth like this

```
let matching = values
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|name| match_value(*name).ok())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

In case of an error `ok()` will return `None` which is then filtered out.
`Ok(T)` values are converted into the origial `T`. So in the end, you will have an `Vec<T>`